# Qual é a diferença entre exceções checadas (checked) e não checadas (unchecked)?

Tags: java, exceção

Olá! Possuo algumas dúvidas sobre exceções, que são elas:

1. Qual é a principal diferença entre exceções checadas e não checadas?
2. Em quais situações devo utilizar cada uma delas?
3. Quais são as boas práticas de uso?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### **Exceções não checadas (unchecked):**

- Representam defeitos no programa (bugs).
- São subclasses de `RuntimeException` e são normalmente implementadas usando  `IllegalArgumentException`, `NullPointerException` ou `IllegalStateException`.
- Um método não é obrigado a estabelecer uma política para as exceções não checadas lançadas por sua execução (e quase sempre nunca o fazem).

**Exemplo de exceção não checada:**

```
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 0;
int res = 0;

res = num1 / num2; // ArithmeticException: / by zero;
```

**Possível solução:**

```
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 0;
int res = 0;

try {
    res = num1 / num2;
} catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Teste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

### **Exceções checadas (checked):**

- Representam condições inválidas em áreas fora do controle imediato do programa (problemas de entradas inválidas do usuário, banco de dados, falhas de rede, arquivos ausentes).
- São subclasses de `Exception`.
- Um método é obrigado a estabelecer uma política para todas as exceções checadas lançadas por sua implementação (ou passar a exceção checada mais acima na pilha, ou manipulá-la de alguma forma).

**Alguns exemplos de exceções checadas:**

```
FileInputStream FIS = null;
FIS = new FileInputStream("D:/arquivo.txt"); // erro: unreported exception FileNotFoundException;

int x;
while ((x = FIS.read()) != 0) { // erro: unreported exception IOException;
}
```

**Possível solução:**

```
FileInputStream FIS = null;
try {
    FIS = new FileInputStream("D:/arquivo.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Teste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
        
int x;
try {
    while ((x = FIS.read()) != 0) {
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Teste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

### **Organização em classes**:

É um pouco confuso, mas note bem que `RuntimeException` (não checada) é por si só uma subclasse de `Exception` (checada).

Já que em alguns casos uma foto vale mais que mil palavras, observe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### **Conclusão:**

O ideal é sempre tratar todas as exceções de seu programa (checadas ou não) e evitar o uso de `throws Exception`.

Qualquer dúvida pergunte nos comentários. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Na figura, a classe `Error` deveria ser unchecked.

Answer (score 9):

## O que é exceção?

> Segundo o famoso [livro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131395319).
>   Nós consideramos os erros detectáveis por hardware, como uma leitura de disco incorreta e situações não convencionais, como um final de arquivo como exceções.
>   Estendemos ainda mais o conceito de exceção para incluir ou condições detectáveis por software.
>
> Portanto, definimos exceção (`exception`) como um evento não usual, causado por erro ou não, que é detectável hardware, software ou ambos e que pode necessitar um tratamento especial.
>
> O processamento especial que pode ser necessário quando uma exceção é detectada é chamado **exception handling**. Este processamento é feito por uma unidade de código ou por um segmento e é chamado de **exception handler**. Um exceção é levantada(**raised**) quando seu evento associado ocorre.
>   Em algumas linguagem baseadas em `C`, exceções são ditas como jogadas(**thrown**) no lugar de levantadas (**raised**)
>
> Nota: `C++` foi a primeira linguagem ao estilo `C` a incluir tratamento de exceção. A palavra **throw** foi usada, no lugar de **raised**, porque a biblioteca padrão do `C` já incluia uma função chama **raise**.

## Quando foram criadas exceções?

> Programming Languages: Principles and Practice, 2nd edition, by Kenneth C. Louden (Um livro notável sobre linguagens de programação) tem uma anotação "A linguagem PL/I foi pioneira no Gerenciamento de exceções na década de 60, e avançou significativamente na linguagem CLU na década de 70. De qualquer maneira foi só na década de 80 e inicio na de 90 que esta questão foi resolvida largamente.

Se tiver uma duvida sobre estas linguagem você pode ver a historia delas [aqui](http://oreilly.com/news/graphics/prog_lang_poster.pdf).

Se quiser saber mais sobre a linguagem `CLU` (http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-561.pdf)

Ref:https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458013/1792268

## Quando foi diferenciado Checked e Unchecked?

O `Java` fez a primeira diferenciação de checked e Unchecked como vemos [aqui](http://www.quora.com/Programming-Languages/What-is-the-origin-of-exception-handling-in-programming-languages) e [aqui](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=26101)

## Mecanismo de exceção no Java?

> Segundo o [livro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131395319).
>
> O mecanismo de exceção do `Java` é baseado no do `C++`, mas é desenhado para ser mais direcionado ao 
>   paradigma orientado a objetos.
>   Todas as exceções são objetos de classes descendente da classe Throwable.
>   O sistema `Java` inclui duas exceções predefinidas que são subclasses de Throwable:Error e Exception.
>   A classes Error e suas descendentes são referentes a error que são lançados pela run-time do Java. Estas exceções nunca são lançadas pelos programas dos usuários, e nunca devem ser tratadas lá.
>   Existem duas descendetes de Exception: RuntimeException e IOException.
>   Na maioria dos casos RuntimeException é lançada quando um programa do usuário causa
>   algum erro.
>   Programas de usuário podem definir suas próprias classes de exceções. A convenção
>   na linguagem `Java` é que exceções definidas pelo usuário sejam subclasses de Exception.
>
> Exceções das classes Error e RuntimeException são chamadas **unchecked exception**.
>   Todas as outras exceções são chamadas **checked exceptions**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe o tutorial da Oracle sobre o tratamento de exceção do Java [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Resumidamente para exceções checadas você é obrigado a capturar a exceção e tratar ela, mesmo que você apenas imprima que ocorreu um erro.

## Atualmente como devo utilizar?

Eu acredito que deve se utilizar exceções não verificadas, como indicado pelo livro de Robert C Martin - Clean Code.

> As exceções verificadas podem às vezes ser úteis se você estiver criando uma biblioteca crítica: é preciso capturá-las. Mas no desenvolvimento geral de aplicativo, os custos da dependência superam as vantagens.

Então utilize principalmente exceções não verificadas a menos que esteja fazendo algo que tem que ser verificado a qualquer custo.

---

Answer (score 5):

Resumidamente as exceções `Checked` são aquelas no qual você é obrigado a tratá-la, seja com um bloco try-catch ou mesmo com um throws (relançando a mesma para outro local). Por outro lado, quando você tem exceções do tipo `Unchecked` não é obrigatório o tratamento da mesma, você pode tratar apenas se quiser, se sentir que é necessário para o bom funcionamento da sua aplicação.
Checked exceptions são utilizadas para erros recuperáveis enquanto que Unchecked exceptions são utilizadas para erros irrecuperáveis. Significa dizer que quando você sabe que seu erro pode ser tratado, você utiliza `Checked Exceptions`, caso contrário utilize `Unchecked Exceptions`.

Comment: Excelente. Explicação simples, mas não menos contundentes que os anteriores. E para forçar um método a ser usado com uma exceção do tipo checked, deve-se usar o statement ```throws``` e o nome da classe ou subclasse a partir de ```Exception``` — sendo a mãe de todas as classes de objetos de tratamento de exceção do tipo checked — imediatamente após o parêntese de fechamento na declaração do método.