# Criação e implementação de classe Exception

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Estou tendo problemas na implementação de uma classe Exception. A explicação do programa é:

> - As strings do vetor devem estar inicializadas com "", e não com null.
> - A capacidade do vetor deve poder ser alterada através de um método.
> - A classe deve ter como atributos (variáveis do objeto) um String[] e um int.
> - Crie os métodos 'String at( int i )' e 'void put( int i, String st )', que respectivamente retornam a String na posição i e mudam o valor da String na posição i.
> - Cada acesso deve ser verificado e se houver um erro de limites, a exceção ArrayIndexOutOfBounds deve ser lançada.
> - Crie um método 'int find( String st )' que retorna a posição de St no vetor, ou -1 se ele não está lá.
> - Se um vetor for redimensionado para um tamanho inferior ao atual, deve-se primeiro eliminar as Strings vazias ("") e verificar se o novo tamanho comporta as Strings restantes. Se não comportar, deve-se lançar uma exceção VectorSizeException (crie essa classe).

A tarefa explicada tá aí, então só preciso saber como fazer pra implementar essa exceção.

Meu código:

A **classe Teste** (não pode ser alterada):

```
package Lab4;

public class Teste {

    public static void main( String argc[] ) {
      StringVector v = new StringVector( 10 );

      v.put( 1, "Janeiro ");
      v.put( 2, "fevereiro" );

      System.out.println( v.at( 3 ) );

      System.out.println( v.at( 13 ) ); // Exceção

      System.out.println( v.at(1));

      v.newSize( 2 ); // OK

      v.newSize( 1 ); // Exceção
    }
}
```

A classe **StringVector** (eu implementei, pode ser alterada):

```
package Lab4;

public class StringVector {
    String[] vetor;
    int inteiro;

    public StringVector (int vectorCapacity) {
        vetor = new String[vectorCapacity];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < vetor.length ; i++) {
            vetor[i] = "";
        }
    }

    public void newSize (int newSize) {

        String[] novo = new String[ newSize ];

        if (newSize < vetor.length) {
            while(find("") != -1) {
                vetor[find("")] = null;
            }

            /*print pra testar o find e a substituição de valores 
            int i = 0;
            while (i < vetor.length) {
            System.out.println(vetor[i]);
            i++;
            }
            */

            completeVector(novo);

/*          try {
                completeVector(novo);
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error) {
                System.out.println("erro: "+ error);
            }*/              
        }
        else {
            completeVector(novo);
        }
    }   

    public String at(int inteiro) {
        try {
            return vetor[inteiro];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error) {
            return "erro: " + error;
        }
    }

    public void put(int inteiro, String st) {
        try {
            vetor[inteiro] = st;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error) {
            System.out.println("erro: " + error);
        }
    }

    public int find(String st) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < vetor.length ; i++) {
            if(st.equals(vetor[i])) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void completeVector (String[] novo) {
        int position = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < vetor.length ; i++) {
            if(vetor[i] != null ) {
                novo[position] = vetor[i];
                position++;
                /*if(position > newSize) {
                    throw new VectorSizeException();
                }*/
            }   
        } 
    }
}
```

E a minha tentativa de **classe Exception:**

```
package Lab4;

public class VectorSizeException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public VectorSizeException () {
        System.out.println("erro: VectorSizeException");
    }       
}
```

Comment: Não consegue fazer o que, especificamente?

Comment: como assim? Onde deve ficar a exceção?

Comment: O que você não sabe fazer? Lançar a exceção?

Comment: Ah, sim. Preciso implementar a classe Exception com aquele nome que tá ali.

Se um vetor for redimensionado para um tamanho inferior ao atual, deve-se primeiro eliminar as Strings vazias ("") e verificar se o novo tamanho comporta as Strings restantes. Se não comportar, deve-se lançar uma exceção VectorSizeException (crie essa classe).

Comment: Exatamente, eu não sei se a minha classe de exceção ta criada corretamente, e não sei como lançar

Comment: Tou fazendo uma explicação pra você =D

Comment: valeu, mt obrigado :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bem, primeiramente (eu creio que) a sua implementação da classe `VectorSizeException` esteja errada. Sintaticamente ela está perfeita, mas semanticamente não faz muito sentido. Exceções devem ser lançadas, neste caso, você apenas mostra na tela o erro. Obviamente para o seu uso, que é simples, isso pode parecer extremamente útil, já em outros casos eu posso te garantir que a utilidade disto é ínfima, senão inexistente.

Então, a classe `VectorSizeException` deveria ser assim

```
public class VectorSizeException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public VectorSizeException (String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Perceba que o construtor pede uma `string` como parâmetro e chama o construtor da *superclasse* passando este argumento recebido como parâmetro. [Na documentação da classe `Exception` você pode ver a definição deste construtor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception(java.lang.String)). Também é possível usar o construtor sem nenhum parâmetro, neste caso eu mantive o parâmetro para ilustrar que uma *exception* pode receber uma **descrição** quando for lançada.

Agora vamos aos pontos do exercício:

O quinto ponto, diz o seguinte

> Cada acesso deve ser verificado e se houver um erro de limites, a exceção ArrayIndexOutOfBounds deve ser lançada.

Os métodos que fazem um acesso ao vetor são **`at`** e **`put`**. Nos dois métodos você comete o mesmo erro, está capturando uma exceção, ao invés lançá-la, como é pedido no exercício. Vejamos o método **`at`**:

```
public String at(int inteiro) {
    try {
        return vetor[inteiro];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error) { 
        return "erro: " + error;
    }
}
```

O bloco `catch` **captura** a exceção que pode ser lançada se houver uma tentativa de acessar um indíce inexistente do *array* chamado `vetor`. O exercício pede para que seja lançada uma exceção do tipo `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` quando ocorrer um acesso indevido.

Logicamente há duas maneiras de se fazer isso: a primeira é deixar correr a exceção normalmente ao tentar acessar uma *posição inválida do array* `vetor`. Por exemplo, uma tentativa de acessar o índice -1, vai causar o lançamento de uma `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Ou seja, só é necessário fazer uma tentativa de acesso indevido. Ilustrando, o método ficaria

```
public String at(int inteiro) {        
    return vetor[inteiro];        
}
```

Você também pode **explicitar** isso (possivelmente é isso que seu professor quer), verificando a posição que se deseja acessar e lançando a exceção manualmente

```
public String at(int inteiro) { 
    if(inteiro < 0 || inteiro => vetor.length) // qualquer coisa fora de 0 e vetor.length -1 é indevido
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();

    return vetor[inteiro];        
}
```

Isso vale também para o método **`put`**.

Agora vamos ao último ponto

> Se um vetor for redimensionado para um tamanho inferior ao atual, deve-se primeiro eliminar as Strings vazias ("") e verificar se o novo tamanho comporta as Strings restantes. Se não comportar, deve-se lançar uma exceção `VectorSizeException` (crie essa classe).

A classe já está criada, eu vou supor que a implementação dos métodos `newSize` e `completeVetor` estejam corretas e partir deste ponto. Perceba que o exercício diz que é necessário **lançar** a exceção.

Vou considerar que a verificação será feita no método `newSize`.

Note que a assinatura do método contém o a instrução `throws`, isso acontece porque `VectorSizeException` é uma *checked-exception* (sempre que herdar de `Exception` será *checked*), então é necessário adicionar isso na assinatura do método. Por via disto, o Java te obriga a tratar esta exceção no momento que for chamar este método ou então adicionar no método esta mesma declaração `throws` na assinatura do método que chamar `newSize` (no seu caso, quem faz isto é o método `main`).

```
public void newSize (String[] novo) throws VectorSizeException {
    // Verificar se o novo tamanho é válido
    if(invalido){ // Se o novo tamanho for inválido
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Alguma mensagem");
    }        
}
```

---

Tem algumas coisas que eu falei na resposta que talvez não fiquem bem claras pra você, então vou deixar aqui algumas referências sobre exceções

- [Qual é a diferença entre exceções checadas (checked) e não checadas (unchecked)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10732/18246)
- [O que são Exceptions?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88831/18246)

Comment: Na verdade ficou tudo absurdamente claro! Muito obrigado pela atenção e pelo comentário! Grande abraço