# O que são checked exceptions?

Tags: exceção, característica-linguagem, independente-de-linguagem

Ao acompanhar uma discussão sobre linguagens de programação, vi pessoas discutindo sobre *checked excpetion* cada uma com seus argumentos a favor ou contra.

Disseram que linguagem tal implementa e linguagem tal não implementa. A minha dúvida é o que são essas *checked exceptions*?

São exceções especiais de alguma linguagem específica?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença entre exceções checadas (checked) e não checadas (unchecked)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10732/28595)

Comment: Isso pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55624/exception-vs-runtimeexception-quando-utilizar-um-ou-outro/55663#55663

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Checked exception* é um mecanismo que tenta, em tese, dar mais robustez para aplicações forçando uma exceção ser tratada de uma forma ou de outra pelo próximo nível na pilha de chamada.

Muitas pessoas consideram que exceção é um mecanismo interessante porque obriga você tratar. Você não tem ideia de quanta gente experiente fala isso porque um dia alguém disse isso e aí a pessoa repete como um papagaio sem ter noção do que está falando. É exatamente o oposto, tem diversos mecanismos que obriga você tratar, mas as pessoas só olham para um que era muito popular e não obriga. Exceção também não obriga, tudo "funciona" ou quebra sem intervenção do programador. Faz parte da filosofia da exceção não obrigar o tratamento, deixar para um outro nível tratar até que chega em um ponto que ninguém tratou e quebra tudo. Veja mais em [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

As exceções verificadas vieram pra mudar isso, só elas de fato obrigam um tratamento logo no primeiro nível. Todo método que lança um exceção e tiver uma [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101), portanto parte do contrato, uma exceção marcada, então quem chamar esse método estará obrigado a tratar a exceção de alguma forma. O mais comum é colocar um `try-catch`, mas é possível colocar na sua assinatura que ele lança essa exceção. Nesse ponto você não precisa mais tratar a exceção logo ali, porque ele delegou e obrigou outro método (que o chamou) a fazer isso. Então não é que você precisa tratar a exceção de forma útil, pode tratar de forma a delegar para outra. Não deixa de ser um tratamento, mesmo sem fazer alguma coisa útil.

Só que as pessoas ficam de saco cheio de lidar com isso e começar usar um monte de `try-catch` vazio só pra satisfazer o código. É errado, claro, mas as pessoas fazem muito, até porque tem situação que o [código não escala bem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364945/101) com tantas exceções checadas. Um dos motivos que métodos novos escritos até mesmo pelo Java opta por não usar tanto assim as tais exceções que deveria dar mais robustez. Não a toa só o Java as adotou (pelo menos entre linguagens *mainstream*). Todo mundo viu depois que foi um erro. Foi querer fazer a linguagem perfeita e deu muito errado. Se a linguagem ajudar, o programador vai fazer errado pra programar do jeito que ele quer.

Por isso questiono até mesmo a criação de exceção, porque quase todo mundo usa errado. Não que eu ache que algo não deva ser posto em uma linguagem porque as pessoas podem usar errado, sou contra essa filosofia (que Java adora tanto, mas só quando é do interesse dela, por exemplo eles não querem sobrecarga de operador onde eu nunca vi em código real alguém abusando, mas exceção que todo mundo abusa o tempo todo, pode ter).

Tá certo que o pessoal não caprichou, mas uma coisa legal dela é que mostra(ria) para a pessoa se aquela exceção é erro de programação e não deve ser tratada (não tem assinatura obrigando) ou é erro da aplicação naquele momento e deve ser tratada (é uma *checked exception*). Pena que desvirtuou tudo e pararam de distinguir isso direito, agora não é mais confiável. E pior, Java considera muito erro de programação como erro de *runtime*.

Um método com uma *checked exception* seria algo assim:

```
public void teste() throws AlgumaException {
    //faz alguma coisa
    if (condicao) throw new AlgumaException();
    //faz alguma coisa
}
```

Aí quem chama tem que fazer algo assim:

```
public void teste2() throws AlgumaException {
    //faz alguma coisa
    teste();
    //faz alguma coisa
}
```

Ou:

```
public void teste() {
    try {
        //faz alguma coisa
    } catch (AlgumaException ex) {
        //faz alguma coisa
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Checked.java).

Fora a obrigatoriedade de tratar elas são idênticas às exceção não checadas. Na prática diminui a robustez das aplicações. Alguém pode argumentar que só porque o programador é desleixado, mas na prática...

Answer (score 1):

**Checked exceptions** são exceções que são identificadas pela linguagem e são passíveis de tratamento, por sua vez são o oposto das **Unchecked exceptions**, mas o que são as Checked? Elas são exceções que são tratadas com um simples *try catch*. Um *input* errado, por exemplo, que pode ser resolvido facilmente. Já uma Unchecked exception seria um *Runtime* como um NullPointerException, onde você não pode tratar o problema, apenas informar ao usuário que ele ocorreu e para sanar o problema a única solução é abrir novamente o *software* ou porção do código acessada. 
Muitos profissionais não fazem o uso dessa boa prática de tratamento das exceções, porém é uma ferramenta útil quando bem utilizada.

Algumas linguagens fazem o uso de Checked exceptions: Java, Pacote .NET(C++,C#....)

[FONTE](http://www.devmedia.com.br/diferenca-entre-checked-e-unchecked-exceptions-em-java/28908)