# Como exceções checadas são identificadas pelo compilador?

Tags: java, exceção

Estive lendo [esta pergunta e suas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10732/164151) e [também esta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214768/164151) mas não entendi bem como o compilador consegue identificar, "nos bastidores", se a exceção é checada ou não.

Sei que `Exception` é a "mãe" das exceções e é checada, mas `RuntimeException` é a "mãe" das exceções que não são checadas e herda da primeira. Mesmo lendo o código-fonte de cada uma delas([¹](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/RuntimeException-source.html) e [²](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Exception-source.html)), não deu muito bem pra entender qual a "mágica" que faz a identificação.

Como o compilador faz essa identificação? É algum mecanismo interno que simplesmente avalia o serial UID delas? É algo mais robusto?

Comment: Em tempo de compilação, suponho que um dos analisadores (acho que o semântico) tem a informação da classe da instância, e pode subir na sua hierarquia de classes até achar se é subclasse de `RuntimeException`, uma espécie de `instanceof`. Se chegar até o topo e não for, então é _checked_. Já em tempo de execução, acho que essa informação se perde, não sei ao certo, mas aí já foi compilado obedecendo ao comportamento esperado, reduzindo a chance de violações. Eu não sei bem como funciona, são só palpites. Mas creio que não vai achar isso no código-fonte da API e sim no do compilador `javac`.

Comment: Faz sentido, será que é open também?

Comment: Presumo que sim, até dei uma pesquisada por curiosidade mas não baixei, tem que baixar um .zip ou .bz2 do repositório Mercurial no site da OpenJDK.

Comment: Piovezan tem razão, a informação sobre as exceções checadas se perde depois de compilar. Tem alguns frameworks que enganam o compilador e criam código que usa exceções checadas secretamente como o lombok ( https://projectlombok.org/ ).

Answer (score -3):

As exceções checadas são identificadas pelo compilador do Java através do uso da palavra-chave throws em uma declaração de método.

Quando o compilador encontra uma declaração de método que inclui a palavra-chave throws, ele sabe que o método pode lançar uma exceção checada e exige que qualquer código que chame esse método inclua uma declaração try-catch ou um bloco throws para lidar com a exceção. Isso garante que todas as exceções checadas sejam tratadas de maneira apropriada no código.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).